# How to access a document library in a sharepoint online site using MS graph

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to access the documents on my one drive with requests like this one:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
```

I am able to access a document library of a root sharepoint site of my company with a request like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children
```

It gives me the contents of the "root" library:

```
https://<my company>.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents
```

I am not able to access the document library of a SP subsite I created. e.g. this one:

```
https://<my company>.sharepoint.com/samplesp/Shared%20Documents
```

How can I access such a document library with MS Graph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For accessing SharePoint sites and lists check out documentation of the [SharePoint API in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint).

**Update:**

For those who have problems with accessing default Drive (formerly "Documents" library) on a specific SharePoint site using MS Graph API:

You should look into the documentation for accessing files on [OneDrive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children).

As said in the question, this endpoint gives us a list of files on private OneDrive:

`.../me/drive/root/children`

Drive on SharePoint's sites works in the same way, but instead of `me` you should provide *global Id* of the site you want to access (*global Id* is `<hostName>,<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>`).

In conclusion: this endpoint gives us a list of files on a specified site's default drive:

`.../Sharepoint/sites/<hostName>,<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>/drive/root/children`

If you want to access files on a specific list, all you need is the id of the list:

`.../Sharepoint/sites/<hostName>,<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>/lists/<listId>/drive/root/children`

Now it should be obvious.

Comment: I see in the beta endpoint how list SharePoint sites. But I don't see how to get their Drive IDs. Any ideas?

Comment: @horacioj You can get Drive ID using endpoint .../beta/Sharepoint/sites/<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>/drive. See my updated answer for more details.

Comment: is there a way to create new drive on a site?  if i want to display a site as a list of folders (where a folder is  a drive) , i want the ability to add new folder to this list

Comment: @RomanGelembjuk You can create a new list with '"template": "documentLibrary"'. Then each new list will be accessible (as a drive) as described in answer.

Comment: Thanks, FIL. But it seems this way is for osme older version of the API. I can not find how to use it with the MS graph API.

Comment: @RomanGelembjuk It's described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/list_create).

Comment: @FIL , that also doesn't help. can you check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900200/ms-graph-api-sharepoint-site-create-a-folder-in-root