# Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph using the .NET SDK

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I know I can use the .NET SDK pointing to the beta endpoint:

```
 public GraphServiceClient(string baseUrl, ...
```

Is it possible to interact with SharePoint sites (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint) using the current [msgraph .NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) (currently, version 1.2.1, Feb 13 2017)?

Or perhaps there is a dev branch implementing this (currently beta) functionality?

What I need is access to the site's files (as it is for OneDrive)
ref.: [How to access a document library in a sharepoint online site using MS graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638790/how-to-access-a-document-library-in-a-sharepoint-online-site-using-ms-graph)

Specifically, I want to know how to handle requests like this via the SDK:

```
/Sharepoint/sites/<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>/drive/root/children

/Sharepoint/sites/<siteCollectionId>,<siteId>/lists/<listId>/drive/root/children
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSGraph .Net Client library is generated from metadata. Currently, we only generate from the v1.0 endpoint metadata. We aren't generating from the beta endpoint. If this feature is important to you, please issue a feature request at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/. If you do post this feature request, please link to it from this SO post.