# MS graph API sharepoint site. Create a folder in root

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I try to use the MS graph API to work with sharepoint sites.
All works fine, except i can not find how to create a folder in root of a site (folders are documents library).

If i know the site id (SITEID) i can list folders in root of the site as drives

```
GET /v1.0/sites/SITEID/drives
```

I have ID for each item (it is like a drive ID). The i can list folders on drives (which are subfolders of top level folders on a site)

```
GET /v1.0/sites/SITEID/drives/DRIVEID/root/children
```

I can create folders in this place and subfolders

```
POST /v1.0/sites/SITEID/drives/DRIVEID/root/children
{
  "name": "New Folder 2",
  "folder": {}
}
```

But how to create a top level folder on a site? In fact, how to create new drive on a site?

I try to guess something like

```
POST /v1.0/sites/SITEID/drives
{
  "name": "New Drive",
  "folder": {}
}
```

But this doesn't work

Also, i tried to create a list https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/list_create

```
POST /v1.0/sites/SITEID/lists
{
  "name": "Books",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Author",
      "text": { }
    },
    {
      "name": "PageCount",
      "number": { }
    }
  ],
  "list": {
    "template": "documentLibrary"
  }
}
```

no success

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong. Folders **are not** document libraries.

Drive is a document library. Document library is a list with *template: document library*, so drive is also a list.

Endpoint

```
GET /v1.0/sites/SITEID/drives
```

will return a list of lists with *template: document library*.

Endpoint

```
GET /v1.0/sites/SITEID/lists
```

will return all lists of all types.

To create new *drive* (a document library) you should create a new list with *document library* as *template*. Then you will have a new drive in a root of the site.

What problem do you have with creation of a new list?

Comment: When i try to repeat this using the API explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer it doesn't work. The request GET /v1.0/sites/SITEID/lists fails with 400 error "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'lists'." And attempt to create a list fails also.
I ensured my auth header have the scope sites.readwrite.all 
What can be wrong?

Comment: What is your SITEID? It should be <hostName>,<siteCollectionId>,<siteId> as described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint#note-for-existing-sharepoint-developers).

Comment: I see in your question that you are using wrong endpoint for creation of the list. It is available only on **beta** version (not v1.0).

Comment: For beta it doesn't work too. GET lists works. But creation of a list returns error . Tried with API explorer