# Can not create a list with MS Graph API (beta)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I try to execute the MS Graph API call described there
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/list_create

It is a creation of a list for a sharepoint site.

I need to create it to be able to make folders in root of my sharepoint sites using the MS graph API . 
My initial request and problem was described there [MS graph API sharepoint site. Create a folder in root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900200/ms-graph-api-sharepoint-site-create-a-folder-in-root)

Noone offered a solution. It looks like the only way to create folders in root of sites is to use this BETA API to create lists.

However, the API doesn't work as described in docs.

When i try to do

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Books",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "Author",
      "text": { }
    },
    {
      "name": "PageCount",
      "number": { }
    }
  ],
  "list": {
    "template": "generic"
  }
}
```

I have an error response with the message

```
Cannot define a 'name' for a list as it is assigned by the server. Instead, provide 'displayName'
```

If i change 'nme' to 'displayName' in the JSON document then error is "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable."

Also i tried to set

```
,"list":{"template":"documentLibrary"}
```

and still same errors

What do i do wrong? Or that BETA API just doesn't work ?

Comment: can you try again with v1?

Comment: This already works. They fixed 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

This API now works. It is released and works as normal v1 (not beta)
There are history on how i communicated with microsoft  about this

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1484